# how to add ondelete parameter to many2many field?

Tags: python-3.x, orm, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

i'm added many2many field that related to the car model 
all records are display in lines 
i need if i delete any data from any column nothing happen to the master model ''car

i'm added ondelete parameter and it doesn't work

```
class item(models.Model):
_rec_name = 'name'
_name = 'item'

related = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="cars", string="related products",required=False, on_delete='NO ACTION', )

class cars(models.Model):
_name = 'cars'

name = fields.Char( string="Car",translate=True, ondelete='NO ACTION')
int_ref = fields.Char(string="Internal reference", required=False,store=True ,ondelete='NO ACTION')
model = fields.One2many(comodel_name="models", inverse_name="car", string="Models", required=False,ondelete='NO ACTION' )
pro = fields.Char(string="profit mergin", required=False, type='int' ,ondelete='NO ACTION')

rang = fields.One2many(comodel_name="yearrange", string="Range", inverse_name="product_id", ondelete='NO ACTION')
start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, ondelete='NO ACTION')
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, ondelete='NO ACTION')
ignore = fields.Char(string="Ignore", required=False,ondelete='NO ACTION' )
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate about your case.

Comment: i have model called Item i'm assigning a field many2many to Car model which have some of fields like years and car models 
if i added any car to item in many2many lines which columns are car, models and years then i need to edit in the line without making any change in the car model

Answer (score 1):

If by deleting you mean when you change for example a value of field
like `start` field and you open the car you in the car menu you find the
original value.

if that's what you want then you are doing it wrong many2many field will change
the original record because it's like a gate to it. what you need to do is
create another model that act's like a relation table.

```py
       class itemCare(models.Model):
            _name = 'items.cars.rel'

            item_id = fields.Many2one.......
            card_id = fields.Many2one.........

            # and you need to repeat all car fields here too
            # I don't know if by doing _inherit = 'cars' will do the trick

            # remove ondelete from cars and here too
            name = fields.Char( string="Car",translate=True, ondelete='NO ACTION')
            int_ref = fields.Char(string="Internal reference", required=False,store=True ,ondelete='NO ACTION')
            model = fields.One2many(comodel_name="models", inverse_name="car", string="Models", required=False,ondelete='NO ACTION' )
            pro = fields.Char(string="profit mergin", required=False, type='int' ,ondelete='NO ACTION')

            rang = fields.One2many(comodel_name="yearrange", string="Range", inverse_name="product_id", ondelete='NO ACTION')
            start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, ondelete='NO ACTION')
            end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, ondelete='NO ACTION')
            ignore = fields.Char(string="Ignore", required=False,ondelete='NO ACTION' )


            @api.onchancge('card_id')
            def onchange_card(self):
                if self.card_id:
                    # fill up all your field with same value of card
                    self.name = self.card_id.name
                    .....
                    .....
                else:
                    # empty all field when we remove the card
                    self.name = False
                    .....
                    ....

        class item(models.Model):
            _rec_name = 'name'
            _name = 'item'

            # the relation now is one2many to the new model that holds the fields of the car
            related = fields.One2many(comodel_name="items.cars.rel", string="related products",required=False )
```

Hope you get the idea, You may find a better solution bu you need a model to store changes that you make
on the item views